# How can i store to List and map?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I want to store to firebase like this....

[image]

My query is this

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('matches').doc(current.uid).set({

'matches.age':hhhhhh,
'matches.picture':hhhhhh,
})
```

Comment: can you provide more details about what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: i have a widget that shows all the list of users, so if a user click on another person information he show show it in matches list...... so user can click as many users as possible

Answer (score 0):

Create sperate list of data and map of data or whatever structure you want and then pass in set method I hope that would be solve your problem.